# WinTECH OPC Client

Tags: opcode

I am trying to connect **WinTECH OPC Client to MaxDNA V6.0.7 server** in local PC and LAN network also. The connection was successfully established but it was showed

> Tag Quality bad" and "Value Unspecified Error

How to solve this issue?

Comment: That's probably niche software, and there's not much detail to go on here. Can you provide any more information? Perhaps the author of that software could help?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.